# Return value from selfmade library in CodeIgniter is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I am having a problem with returning a value from  a library back to the controller.
When I echo the return value it shows nothing, but when I echo it in the library instead of returning it does show the whole thing.

This is the controller:

```
$this->load->library('lib_registration');
$message = $this->lib_registration->create_email($registerData);
echo $message;
```

This is the library:

```
<?php
class lib_registration
{
public function create_email($incomingData)
{
    $name = $incomingData['name'];
    $lastname = $incomingData['lastname'];
    $email = $incomingData['email'];
    $password = $incomingData['password'];

    $this->return_email($name, $lastname, $email, $password);
}

public function return_email($name, $lastname, $email, $password)
{
    $emailMessage = '
        <p>Beste '.$name.' '.$lastname.'</p>
        <p>
            Ten eerste heten wij u welkom bij BodyBook. Uw online medische dossier waarin u bepaalt wat er in staat.
            Privacy staat bij ons heel hoog en wij respecteren ook de privacy van anderen. Daardoor willen wij u 
            er gelijk op wijzen dat u zelf beslist wat in uw online dossier komt te staan en wat zichtbaar is voor anderen.
        </p>
        <p>
            Ten tweede heeft u zojuist een account aangemaakt bij BodyBook.
            Hieronder staat uw voorlopig wachtwoord om mee in te loggen.
            Gelieve dit wachtwoord gelijk te veranderen op het moment dat uw voor het eerst inlogt.
        </p>
        <p>
            Uw wachtwoord = <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px"><strong>'.$password.'</strong></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            Onthoudt dit wachtwoord goed. Dit wachtwoord is beveiligd opgeslagen en kan daarom niet worden opgevraagd.
            Mocht u uw wachtwoord vergeten zijn, dan is daar een optie voor tijdens het inloggen.
            Mocht u uw wachtwoord willen wijzigen, dan kan dat in uw account instellingen als u bent ingelogd.
        </p>
        <p>
            Wij wensen u veel plezier met BodyBook.
        </p>
        <p>
            Met Vriendelijk Groet,
        </p>
        <p>
            Het BodyBook team.
        </p>
        ';

    return $emailMessage;
}
}
?>
```

I hope you guys can show me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The create_email function needs a return as well. Like this...

```
public function create_email($incomingData)
{
    $name = $incomingData['name'];
    $lastname = $incomingData['lastname'];
    $email = $incomingData['email'];
    $password = $incomingData['password'];

    return $this->return_email($name, $lastname, $email, $password); //return here
}
```

Comment: Seems this was the problem. Now it works as it is supposed to be. Thanks